# Putting yourself in danger?

Tags: halacha

Suppose that you want to wear an IDF shirt to show your support for the army while you’re on the train. Also suppose it *might* be dangerous because of a so called “day of jihad”. Would Judaism encourage not wearing the shirt and not putting your life potentially in danger, or would we say be loud and proud and there’s no problem wearing it.
Also, the IDF shirt can be swapped out for lets say a kippa, or wearing your tzizit hanging out.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is asking people to weigh the danger associated with wearing a shirt on a train on a particular day against the demonstrative value of same shirt, as opposed to other options. I think that both the supposed danger and the supposed comparative value are matters that need to be evaluated by the hypothetical individual facing such a dilemma; we can't do that for him or her.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Halacha forbids to put oneself in danger [(Orach Chaim, Choshen Mishpat 427:8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.427.8). However, from the Gemara in [Pesachim 8a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.8a.17), we can learn that when a person goes to perform a mitzvah, even when that is in a difficult period or dangerous location, he will be safe

> Those on the path to perform a mitzva are not susceptible to harm
> throughout the process of performing the mitzva

Is wearing an IDF-shirt considered a mitzvah? Surely it is a great virtue to show compassion to your fellow, but I don't think this can be categorised under a mitzvah. Certainly if you know in advance that you take a train full of Palestinian-supporters, would it be wise to wear the shirt?

Comment: What about for the tzizit? Because in this case it’s not that your going to do the mitzvah like the Gemara says, it’s that you’re actively doing it.

Comment: I am sure there can be found something with regard to hiding your tzitziis due to violence. However, I have not found anything.

Comment: I'm not sure if currently doing a mitzva and "on the way to do a mitzva" are the same

Comment: What's the applicative definition of "in danger"? Does it apply here?